# I can't proceed with linear algebra for eigenvector and eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Q. Find the solution of the difference equations $x_n+_1$ = A$x_n$  with initial condition $x_0$ at time n = 1004 when $A$ is\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\4&-2\end{bmatrix} and $x_0$ is \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}

I find eigenvectors and eigenvalues
 $v_1$ = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\4\end{bmatrix}
$v_2$ = \begin{bmatrix}1\\4\end{bmatrix}

but i can't proceed more.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake with your eigenvectors.  You should instead have
$$
\lambda_1 = -3,\   v_1 = (-1,4) \qquad \lambda_2 = 2, \  v_2 = (1,1).
$$
Now, solve the system of equations
$$
c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 = x_0.
$$
Once you have the numbers $c_1,c_2$, we have
$$
A^n x_0 = A^n(c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2) = c_1 A^n v_1 + c_2 A^n v_2.
$$